# How to show the sql sentences when someone alter Oracle table

Tags: oracle

I have a Oracle DB used by many people. I want to know exactly what someone do when alter a table and insert this into a log history table.

Comment: Maybe you should start reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/cdc.htm#i1025454)

Comment: @JeroenHeier thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started

```
DROP TABLE DDL_LOG CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
/

CREATE TABLE DDL_LOG
(
  TSTAMP       TIMESTAMP(6)                     NOT NULL,
  HOST         VARCHAR2(100),
  IP_ADDRESS   VARCHAR2(100),
  MODULE       VARCHAR2(100),
  OS_USER      VARCHAR2(100),
  TERMINAL     VARCHAR2(100),
  OPERATION    VARCHAR2(100),
  OWNER        VARCHAR2(50),
  OBJECT_NAME  VARCHAR2(50),
  OBJECT_TYPE  VARCHAR2(50),
  SQLTEXT      CLOB,
  PREVSQLTEXT  CLOB
)
/


DROP TRIGGER capture_all_ddl
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CAPTURE_ALL_DDL
after create or alter or drop on database
begin
    insert into ddl_log
    values (systimestamp,
                sys_context('USERENV','HOST'),
                sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS'),
                sys_context('USERENV','MODULE'),
                sys_context('USERENV','OS_USER'),
                sys_context('USERENV','TERMINAL'),
                ora_sysevent,
                ora_dict_obj_owner,
                ora_dict_obj_name,
                ora_dict_obj_type,
                case when ora_dict_obj_type not in ('PACKAGE','PROCEDURE','FUNCTION','PACKAGE BODY') and ora_sysevent != 'DROP' then
                  ( select sql_fulltext from v$sql
                    where sql_id = ( select sql_id from v$session where sid = sys_context('USERENV','SID') and rownum = 1 )
                  )
                end,
                case when ora_dict_obj_type not in ('PACKAGE','PROCEDURE','FUNCTION','PACKAGE BODY') and ora_sysevent != 'DROP' then
                  ( select sql_fulltext from v$sql
                    where sql_id = ( select prev_sql_id from v$session where sid = sys_context('USERENV','SID') and rownum = 1 )
                  )
                end
           );
     commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: Is it require sysdba to compile?`DBMS_System.ksdwrt` must be declare.

Comment: Connor - I thought DBMS_SYSTEM is undocumented and unsupported by Oracle. Shouldn't you have included a caveat regarding that in your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AUDIT to capture and write log.

Comment: While this might solve the problem, your answer would be better if it described how it can be implemented.